# clicking on particular link without using qtp function

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Can anybody help me out clicking on particular static link on webpage without  using QTP function?
I tried using WebLink after browse.page.WebLink then operation.

Comment: There is no such thing as `WebLink` did you try `Link`?

Comment: May be you can bring the cursor focus on the link using SendKeys and once your brought the focus on test link, you can perform ENTER....! If it's not relevant to your requirement, then do give bit more information about your requirement that why do you need to perform something out of QTP!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the reason you don't want to use QTP's click function, but you can try to hit the object at the DOM level with Browser().Page().Link().object.click (which really is the same as the B.P.L.Click method but at a lower level).